# Has someone found a way to cascade forms in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

What I am trying to achieve, while having 3 different forms in one view, is to have the data on the other forms also get updated. Example:

- form 1 for basic data
- form 2 for load picture
- form 3 for select pictures

When the user uploads the selected file, then the info he has entered on the other forms should not get deleted, showing empty forms.

Example code:

```
<?php
// form 1 Will call the controller/model, prozess the data, and return to the view

echo form_open('test_controller/add_something');
echo form_input($input1);
echo form_textarea($txt_area1);
echo form_submit(array('id'=>'submit','value'=>'Save));
echo form_close();

// form 2 Will call the controller/model, process the data, and return to the same view ?>

<form name="uploadformular" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="dateiupload" method="post">
    Datei: <input type="file" name="uploaddatei" size="60" maxlength="255">
    <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Datei hochladen">
</form>

<?php
// form 3 Will call the controller/model, process the data, and return to the same view

echo form_open('same_controller/add_detail_entry');
echo form_input($input2);
echo form_textarea($input3);
echo form_submit(array('id'=>'submit','value'=>'Save));
echo form_close();
?>
```

Comment: what does prevent you from merging the 3 forms into one form and then handle the logic into your controller??

Comment: I actually thought about this aproach, but could not find a way how to call different functions (when presing different Buttons) on the Controller. You have an idea?

Comment: what do you mean by - call different functions (when pressing different Buttons) on the Controller- ? if you merge all your forms into one form you will have only one submit button.

Comment: I think you need to use Ajax. It allows you to update some parts of the page without having to reload the whole page and lose other inputs.

Comment: @Amr Aly: I have 3 forms each one with a button. Each form work for it self, but will delete what's on the other two forms. This is what I am trying to avoid. I need all 3 forms, or I will have to make 3 views if I don´t use AJAX (Java script is not always available in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree to both [Amr Aly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7234275/amr-aly) and [ITWitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2562819/itwitch).

First you can use on Submit call to do all the functions But if you persist on choosing the method you want. Give Ids to the forms like

```
<form id="form1" action="url1" method="post"></form>
<form id="form2" action="url2" method="post"></form>
<form id="form3" action="url3" method="post"></form>
```

and instead of using input type = submit. Use button and write a JavaScript function for it which gets the ID of the form and submits it.